# latitude and longitude both undefined in api link

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation, undefined

my latitude and longitude are both undefined in the api link when i check it in my console. what are my doing wrong?.

Here's my code

```js
var Geo= {};
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
else {
alert('Geolocation is not supported');
}


function showPosition(position) {
      Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
}
    
  // var btc = document.querySelector('#price');
//listen for clicks
window.onload = function() {
  // window.onload = function() { if want to load it immediately without d click of a btn
//make request
  var btcP = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var requestUrl ="https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + Geo.lat + "&lon=" + Geo.lng + "";
  console.log(requestUrl);
```

Comment: perhaps `window.onload` is running before `showPosition` get's a chance to be called - try putting the code that's in window.onload inside  showPosition instead, to properly deal with asynchronism

Comment: You're probably right. I'll give it a try. thanks @JaromandaX